# some issues for loading Json file in Python

Tags: python, json

I am a new pythoner, now I want to read a Json file having size 250MB which is quite big for my memory. This file contains thousands of groups of user data.

One example as follow for a group of user data:

```
{"votes": {"funny": 0, "useful": 0, "cool": 0}, "user_id": "0a2KyEL0d3Yb1V6aivbIuQ", "review_id": "IjZ33sJrzXqU-0X6U8NwyA", "stars": 5, "date": "2011-07-27", "text": "I have no idea why some people give bad reviews about this place. It goes to show you, you can please everyone. That goes to show you that  you have to try these things yourself because all these bad reviewers have some serious issues.", "type": "review", "business_id": "ZRJwVLyzEJq1VAihDhYiow"}
```

My target is to build bag of word model for each user according to the "Text" tag. So my current ideas is to load this big file. But I think my memory cannot support this workload. So is there good idea for this task or if we can cut the file into buch of files which each file corresponding to each user data?

Comment: What are the issues you are facing? I mean is memory consumptions the problem?

Comment: Is the overall format `[{"votes": ...}, {"votes": ...}, ...]` or is it an array within an object or something else?

Comment: 250MB isn't particularly large - I wouldn't optimise this until you see a problem in practice.  If the data is uniform, as @icktoofay asks, then you could pre-process the json string if necessary.

Comment: @sapi: Many of the cheaper VPS offerings have only 512 MB of RAM. A 250 MB string fills up about half of that. Once you parse the string out into the data structures, it could easily eat up the rest and then some. I guess swap might mitigate this, but as everyone knows, swapping kills performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you keep the user data in [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/) or some other DB and wrap in an [lru_cache](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

The reasoning being that as it's not possible to keep all that data in memory, you'll need to keep some on disk.  Once you have to juggle which data is in memory vs which is on disk, then it's best to use a database to do it for you.